# Error: an Ember.CollectionView's content must implement Ember.Array.

Tags: ember.js, render

i want to render a template with render helper. the page take an error:

> an Ember.CollectionView's content must implement Ember.Array

http://jsbin.com/ikituj/62/edit

Answer (score 1):

**The render helper**

First, one minor change. When you call `{{render "blogcategory" App.BlogCategory}}`, you should (optionally) be passing an *instance* of the BlogCategory model as the second parameter to `render`, not the *class*. See more on the [render helper](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/#toc_the-code-render-code-helper)

**The error**

So, changing that line to `{{render "blogcategory"}}`, we still get the error:

```
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: an Ember.CollectionView's content must implement     Ember.Array. You passed <(generated blogcategory controller):ember326>
```

**Why is this happening?**

This is because Ember is not picking up on your BlogCategoryController. See how the error says you're passing in `(generated blogcategory controller)`? This means that Ember has auto-generated a controller -- **not** the `BlogCategoryController` that you defined (which extends `ArrayController` and *does* implement `Ember.Array`).

When you call `{{render 'blogcategory'}}` in your blogs template, by convention, Ember looks for a view named `Blogcategory` and a controller named `BlogcategoryController`. Notice the capitalization -- Ember doesn't know when to capitalize your classes for you! Because it can't find either, it autogenerates an ObjectController, and then it complains when you try to iterate over it with `{{#each}}` in the blogcategory template.

**The fix**

The solution is to either change your render call or your controller name so they match. I went with changing the call to `render` because your controller name (BlogCategoryController) already follows convention.

1. I changed `{{render 'blogcategory'}}` to `{{render 'blogCategory'}}`
2. I changed the id on the `blogcategory` template to `id=blogCategory`.

See here:
http://jsbin.com/ikituj/66/edit

Comment: Sorry, could you please clarify your question?

Comment: when call {{render 'blogcategory'}}, the blogcategory template is null,, where‘s the blogcategory.model point.

http://jsbin.com/ikituj/76/edit